# If I have a transaction_id of an authorization request in Magento, can I use same that transaction id and token to capture funds in Salesforce?

Tags: magento-1.9, authorize.net, salesforce-service-cloud, authorize.net-cim

So I am using Salesforce and Magento for order management in the backend. My customers are placing orders on my marketplace in Magento and then Magento sends the orders to salesforce for reporting. I would like process the orders in salesforce; however, I don't want to be flagged to xss attack or middle man attack by Authorize.net. I want to know if I can use the transaction token and ID that I received for authorizing amount on the customer's card in Magento to capture the funds in Salesforce?

Magento makes api call to authorize.net to auth amount on customer's credit card.
Then Salesforce uses that same authorization token in capture funds.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. As long as you have the proper login ID, transaction ID, and CIM profiled IDs the payment can originate from any system you control.